# Android- Logic behind setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am new to Java/Android programming and unfortunately I  don't fully under stand the logic behind this piece of code:

```
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

I have alredy read a whole lot of tutorials about it but unfortunately in no one so far the code gets explained in detail. Maybe because it's so basic that every decent object oriented programmer would understand the reason for the structure right away.

I am wondering why do I need to use `new View.OnClickListener()`as a parameter? for the `setOnClickListener` method. In other words why doesn't something like

```
         button.setOnClickListener(
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
     });
```

this work?

Besides that I am not quite sure why the `onClick` method requires the paramterer of `View v`.

I would be quite thankful for some help since I am currently rather puzzled.

Comment: Easy said: because the setOnClockListener takes a View.OnClickListener instance as input. The onClick(View v) is just a method within View.OnClickListener. So passing View v as parameter is not enough as this is just View instance.

Comment: Inaddition to the answers, if you're new to object oriented programming, you should also read about interface, polymorphism and obsever pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`View.OnClickListener` is an interface which you need to implement when you want to handle click events. In your code, you are doing that by doing `new View.OnClickListener()`. Here you are actually creating an anonymous class that implements `View.OnClickListener`.  And any class that implements `View.OnClickListener` must also implement all the methods declared in it (e.g. the `onClick` method). Also, in `public void onClick(View v) {..}`, 
the `View v` denotes the view or the button that was clicked so that you can perform whatever you want with it. For example, get it's id, change it's color etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so first of all onClick method wants a parameter as a function. The thing is in Java you can't send a function as a parameter as you can do in other languages (like C++). The Java solution is to use a **Functional Interface**.

In this case OnClickListener is an interface that have one method you must implement : public void onClick(View v). View v it's the view you just clicked so the method it's called.

button.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener) means the set... function needs an argument that implements the OnClickListener.

So that what this code does :

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

It is creating an anonymous class that implements the OnClickListener interface required.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the case where it would be like what you defined - you do not pass in a parameter and simply describe the actions to be taken when that button is pressed. It will work perfectly but for that button only. You will have to redo this method for every other button. What in the case where there are quite a few buttons that do the same thing? You will end up redefining it every time. Wouldn't it be easier to simply just do it once and then pass that in? Also wouldn't it be easier to simply just have one onClick() method which identifies the id of the element being clicked and then performs the logic just for the widget with that id rather than having laborious separate lines of code?

Also don't forget that the parameter being passed belongs to the View class which is the superclass of every other widget. So you can pass the onClickListener() method defined for other widgets into this method if you want (though this case is practically rare).

To answer your question, the Android team could have designed it to be the way you described but chose to do it this way due to best practices and programming paradignms.